# modify first number from a read file c language

Tags: c

```
int main()
{

 FILE *file=fopen("numbers.dat","rb");

    int number;

    if(file ==NULL)
        exit(0);
    while(fread(&number,sizeof(int),1,file))
        printf("%d",number);


return 0 ;

}
```

Comment: What is your question? What didn't work?

Comment: i would like to modify the first even number .Might you help with that

Comment: If you want to modify the file, you need to open it in with the write mode. "r+" allows you to update the file both reading and writing, you can use several functions such as fprintf to write to the file

Answer (score 0):

The code below opens a file in read/write bytes mode and writes a number to the beginning of the file without erasing its content, is that what you need ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {
   FILE * fp;
   int a = 12;

   fp = fopen ("titi", "rb+");
   fwrite(&a, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
   fclose(fp);
   return(0);
}
```

If you want to read it first, you might want to look at the `fseek()` function to place your file cursor back at the beginning of the file or open the file twice, once to read it and once to write to it.